# Does a plugin or extension framework exist for windows mobile applications

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, plugins, compact-framework

I am looking for a .NET Compact plugin or extension framework similar to the full framework [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://mef.codeplex.com/) provided by MS Patterns and Practices.

It is to be used to dynamically and generically load and manage assemblies that will provide both hardware capabilities as well as user feature modules to the client application.

Anyone know of anything?

Answer (score 1):

What are you after that, say, a Dependency Injection framework like the [OpenNETCF IoC framework](http://ioc.codeplex.com) wouldn't provide?  A DI framework provides extremely loose coupling (components are loaded via reflection), a dynamic mechanism for loading assemblies (loaded via XML file, though that behavior can be overridden), and objects are typically discoverable though one or more object collections.

Whether these items are user or hardware features would be completely up to you and how they are written.

Comment: thanks! I will check it out, it seems to be more or less what I am after. 

You mentioned the loading behaviour (from XML file) can be overridden, do you know if the framework will support loading of assemblies that come in through an update process and as such, whose details are not known at design time? (basically some combination of Assembly.Load() and a bit of reflection and folder traversing post-app update)

Comment: The framework will load anything that derives from specific interfaces.  The code is wide open, so if it doesn't do what you wan't you can always add it.